# How can I know if a column contains empty cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, null, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm probably missing something because it seems like a basic question to me but I couldn't find anything related online.
Context: I'm creating a spreadsheet to keep track of my expenses which is a simple table with these columns { Description, Category, Date, Amount }. I forget to input some of these field when I register a new expense sometimes. So the question is: how can I check for blank cells (the ones I forget to input) in a given column? I obviously want to ignore all the empty ones that there are after the last valid cell at the bottom of the column.

This is the only formula I've tried: **=ISBLANK(A1:A)** but it doesn't work as expected because it works only with single cells and not with column. Or at least this is what I've understood.

Comment: *color-highlighting* the blank cells using `conditional formatting` could be one option...

Comment: =arrayformula(isblank(A:A))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no way usurps doubleunary's superb answer, but if you simply want to know if a column has some empty cells prior to the last filled cell, you could use the following (e.g. for column A):

```
=ArrayFormula(countblank(offset(A:A,,,xmatch(1,n(A:A<>""),0,-1)))>0)
```

`n(A:A<>"")` returns an array of `1` for filled cells & `0` for empty ones. `xmatch(1,n(A:A<>""),0,-1)` finds the index of the last filled cell in this array by searching it bottom-to-top for the first `1` it encounters. This index is then fed into `offset` as the height parameter to return the original A:A range truncated to the last filled cell. `countblank` then simply counts the number of blanks in this truncated range, and if it is >0 returns `TRUE` as there are therefore blank cells present.

Comment: doubleunary's answer was superb indeed but this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

To add a textual note of missing data in columns `A1:D`, put this formula in row `1` of a free column:

```
=let( 
  range, A1:D, 
  columnnames, query(range, "limit 0", 1), 
  lastRow, max(sort(row(range) * iferror(range <> ""))), 
  byrow(filter(range, row(range) <= lastRow), lambda(r, let( 
    missing, filter(columnNames, isblank(r)), 
    ifna("Missing: " & textjoin(", ", true, missing)) 
  ))) 
)
```

The results will look like this:

| Description | Category | Date | Amount |  | *(formula here)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| beans |  | 2023-10-30 | $16.00 |  | Missing: Category |
| rye flour | groceries | 2023-10-30 | $15.00 |  |  |
| car charging | electricity |  | $14.00 |  | Missing: Date |
| boat NY–Southampton | travel | 2023-10-30 |  |  | Missing: Amount |
| oatmeal |  |  |  |  | Missing: Category, Date, Amount |
|  | electricity | 2023-10-30 | $18.00 |  | Missing: Description |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) ,
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197)
and
[textjoin()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to count cells with something in them:

```
=countif(F1:F20,"<>")
```

So then you can just subtract this from the number of rows to get the count with nothing in them:

```
=rows(F1:F20)-countif(F1:F20,"<>")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to do this in Excel for the web or Office 365:

=BYROW(A2:D7,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR("Missing: "&TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A1:D1,ISBLANK(x))),"")))

[image: How can I know if a column contains empty cells in Excel?]

Comment: This question is regarding Google Sheets.